# Loop will run once at most, (loop increment never executed)

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, uipickerview

I have a picker view and I want the the things in it to be the tail numbers of the planes. I use this code, but I get the warning `Loop will run once at most, (loop increment never executed)`, and then I get the error `control may each end of non-void function.` What is wrong here?

**CODE:**

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    for (NSInteger i = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"planeNum"]; (i = 0); i--) {
        NSString *dTailNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Plane%liTailNumber", i]]];
        return dTailNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend the `for` conditional to be `i != 0` and not `i = 0`?

Comment: He probably did, but that wouldn't eliminate either the warning or the error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason you get the warning

> Loop will run once at most, (loop increment never executed)

Is because you have an unconditional `return` in the body of the loop.  On the first execution of the loop, it will `return` out of the method before the loop increment is reached.

---

The reason you get the

> control may reach the end of a non-void function

is because there's no guarantee for this function to ever return anything.  What if the loop executes 0 times?  Then the method never returns anything, which isn't okay since it's declared as returning an `NSString`.

Comment: So can I somehow say if the Loop doesn't run, return Make a new plane on the home screen?

Comment: Outside and under the loop, add a `return` statement to return whatever `NSString` (or `nil`) you want.  However in this specific instance, I think I'd just get rid of the loop altogether and eliminate both problems.

Comment: And how is the first thing fixed? Confused with you response.

Comment: Do you understand that once you `return` out of a method, nothing else in the method is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Way too much thinking about it.  It is quite simple (took me a minute to figure it out too!)

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    // set a blank string
    NSString *dTailNumber = @"";
    for (NSInteger i = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"planeNum"]; (i = 0); i--) {
        // no need to declare here now
        dTailNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Plane%liTailNumber", i]]];
        // this is removed from loop
        // return dTailNumber;
    }
    // instead return here
    return dTailNumber;

}
```

The method itself will first make sure (self) will return the appropriate property (NSString *)...BEFORE IT RUNS ANY UNDERLYING CODE...period!   I always forget that the compiler simply checks for everything needed and then runs all inner functions!  Pretty cool when you figure it out!