# Loop will run at most once (loop increment never executed) in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop

I have checked [same question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586891/loop-will-run-once-at-most-loop-increment-never-executed)
but I can't understand how it's related in my scenario? Please check my code

```
UITextField *textFieldData=(UITextField *)textField;
NSMutableDictionary *dictFields = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictFields setObject:[[dictCustomFieldGroups valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:textFieldData.tag] forKey:@"fieldname"];
[dictFields setObject:textFieldData.text forKey:@"fieldvalue"];
[dictFields setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)textFieldData.tag] forKey:@"tagvalue"];

if ([arrFields count] > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i< [arrFields count]; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        dict = [arrFields objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([[dict valueForKey:@"tagvalue"] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)textFieldData.tag]]) {
            [arrFields replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dictFields];
            break;
        } else {
            [arrFields addObject:dictFields];
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    [arrFields addObject:dictFields];
}
```

I am getting this warning in my for loop.

Comment: Unrelated but it's a very bad idea to modify an array while being enumerated.

Comment: Hint: use a debugger and single-step through your method. You'll immediately see what's wrong.

Comment: @vadian any suggestion how to replace the array outside the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written `break` in both `if` and `else` condition. Thus, the loop breaks, after running once - irrespective of your condition being correct or false.

Additionally as pointed out in the comment, you should not modify the array while it is being used in a loop - it might work in this case, given you are `replacing`, however, it can lead to crashes etc, if not very careful. Infact, in `else` condition you are adding extra elements, which is definitely going to disturb the iteration.

Comment: please mark answer as correct, if it helped you. Thank-you.

Comment: any suggestion? because I need to replace that.

Comment: make a different dictionary, put index and new value. After your iteration over array is done, iterate over dictionary to get the index and value that needs to be put and replace it in the original array.

Comment: Please try and implement, if there's a bug or something, please feel free to ask another question. Will help there. Please mark this answer as correct, if is sufficed the original question you asked.